# Gallery View with loading Footer

Tags: android, android-gridview

Can anybody have any idea of how to achieve below?

*From Android Market*

[image]

I have achieve with listview in my App by adding footerview dynamically while the app is Loading. Now the requirement has been changed and they want to use gridview. and I am having trouble with putting loading in footerview. Mine become like the following img.

*this is mine.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

above library supports gridview and all the other adapterview

Comment: Thanks. It look likes what I want. But after I looking at the code it is a lot complicated. And Using lib is not our preference. Is there anyway to tweak the default android gridview?